# How to determine the position of character in a text file, (C++)

Tags: c++, file, char

I'm trying to count the position of different characters in a text file, but I'm having troubles.The objective is to read a file, identify the position of each first instance of each upper/lower case letter and the first instance of digits (0-9), with whitespace counting as influence to the position of a character.  I'm doing so with a function, but have hit a wall. 
I've hardcoded some things mainly for testing/reference purposes. 
Using the below code only outputs "S", and no position quantity (outputted as a string). 
I'm assuming the primary error has to be from reading the file incorrectly. I'm trying to read it all at once and then parse through it to see if the character I'm testing for matches.

Code Below:

```
//function


string position_upper_alpha(char upper_letter){
    string line;
    int location=0;
    string val;
    string iname;
    iname = "testing.txt";
    ifstream ist {iname};     // ist is an input stream for the file named name
    if (!ist) error("can't open input file ",iname);
    getline ( ist, line );
    for (int i=1;i<line.length();i++){
    if (line.at(i)==upper_letter){
        location=i;
        break;
    }
}
    if(location ==0){
        val="Not Found";
}
    return val;
}



int main(){

//arbitrary character for testing 
char test = 'S';
cout<<test<<position_upper_alpha(test);

}
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you return an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is flawed since you are reading the text line by line and comparing the characters of the lines using an index that corresponds only to the line, not the entire file.

I suggest changing the return value to a signed integral type so you can return -1 if the character is not found and the index of the character in the file when it is found.

```
long position_upper_alpha(char upper_letter)
{
   string iname = "testing.txt";
   ifstream ist {iname};
   if (!ist) error("can't open input file ",iname);

   int c;
   long location = 0;
   for ( ; (c = ist.get()) != EOF; ++location )
   {
      if ( c == upper_letter )
      {
         return location;
      }
   }

   return -1;
}
```

Comment: A couple of followups:
I'm trying to output either the position, or "Not Found" if the character doesn't exist in the file. Couldn't I just make the function return a "string" type value?

Comment: you can test `if(position_upper_alpha(something) == -1)` and output whatever you want :). Moreover you can edit the function written by R Sahu to do the test inside and return a `string`.

Comment: @ztalira _"A couple of followups"_ [How to heal help vamirism?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)